# how to increase textbox number on every page load in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am looking for a code where value of textbox is autogenrate number and change number on every page load in HTML ,Javascript or PHP

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem, post some code. My suggestion would be to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Can you please elaborate your situation?

Comment: Do you mean auto generated number??

Answer (score 1):

**U can use Session in php to do this.**

```
<?php

session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION["number"]))
{
$_SESSION["number"] = rand(1,1000);

}



$_SESSION["number"]=$_SESSION["number"]+1;


?>

<input type='text' name='incrimented_values' value=<?=$_SESSION["number"]?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

Somting like this wil work:

Make a pageload.php

```
<?Php 
if (!isset($Pageload)) {  $Pageload = 0; }//set 0 for first load 

$Pageload = $Pageload++;  // incrise pageload

 ?>
```

Include the foloing on every page:

```
<?Php 
set_include_path('/webside/php/pageload.php');

Echo "<input type='text' name='pageload' value='$pageload'>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
<input type="text" value="<?=rand()?>" name="random_number">
```

For more details about `rand` [check this](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_math_rand.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the rank/count of the website of total number of visited user, then you can use this.

1) got to this site   :  http://www.counter12.com/
2) then use this script

```
<div align=center><a href='http://www.counter12.com'><img src='http://www.counter12.com/img-BYb3CD4x89YyzYdY-27.gif' border='0' alt='counter'></a><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.counter12.com/ad.js?id=BYb3CD4x89YyzYdY'></script></div>
```

**or**

if you want to count start manually then use

```
<?Php 
if (!isset($Pageload)) {  $Pageload = 0; }//set 0 for first load 
$Pageload = $Pageload++;  // incrise pageload
Echo "<input type='text' name='pageload' value='$pageload'>"; ?>
```